# Multiplying price by user quantity to get amount GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Using Eclipse to Create a GUI that has a JPanel that displays the item, price, Quantity and Amount of everything.
There are four txtFields above the JPanel for the user to enter the quantity of each item. Below is an extract of code that displays everything in the JPanel.

// Items

```
g2dImg.drawString("Item", 5, 20);
g2dImg.drawString("Price", 95, 20);
g2dImg.drawString("Quantity", 190, 20);
g2dImg.drawString("Amount", 315, 20);
```

// Price of Items

```
g2dImg.drawString(nf.format(pBurger), 95, 50);
g2dImg.drawString(nf.format(pChips), 95, 85);
g2dImg.drawString(nf.format(pSalad), 95, 125);
g2dImg.drawString(nf.format(pJuice), 95, 160);
```

// Quantity of items

```
g2dImg.drawString(txtBurger.getText(), 190, 50);
g2dImg.drawString(txtChips.getText(), 190, 85);
g2dImg.drawString(txtSalad.getText(), 190, 125);
g2dImg.drawString(txtJuice.getText(), 190, 160);
```

// Amount of items (Quantity x Price)

```
g2dImg.drawString(nf.format(pBurger) * (txtBurger.getText(), 95, 50));
```

Not sure how to go about this part^ Am I on the right track or completely off?

Comment: What do you want with this line `g2dImg.drawString(nf.format(pBurger) * (txtBurger.getText(), 95, 50));`?

Comment: Don't use `drawString(..)` for data that is obviously better suited to being displayed in other GUI elements such as `JTextField` or `JTable`.

Comment: I want to multiply the amount of the item by the quantity entered by the user. The line is probably completely wrong. Still new to programming and just doing this for first assignment. Thinking that i might have to go about it another way